# Can these tree trunks be used for a small table?

Tags: wood

The other day I found these two sections of a tree trunk in the street. So I'm wondering, can they be prepared to be used as some type of rustic stump table?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a woodworking.se where this might fit better.  Ther are some real experts there who will be able to advise you on how to avoid cracking as the wood seasons, and how long the process will take.  But whether it migrates or not, your question would benefit from knowing what type of wood it is

Comment: If you do choose to work with raw wood like this, make sure to kill off any parasites and wood-eating bugs which might be hidden inside.  How to do that would be another great question to ask over on the woodworking se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can - Absolutely! As @Henry Taylor suggests: it would be a good idea to kill off parasites, termites, etc.

1. If you cut or sand-down the ends, be sure they are level so the top of your table is not at an angle.
2. You can choose to coat the top with a urethane coating, or just lay a piece of glass, plexiglass, or polycarbonate over the top so you have a smooth top.
3. If you wish, they also make great planters. You can carve or gouge a hole in the top; drill a hole for water to drain from, and either put a pot in it with flowers or just fill it with dirt and directly plant something in it.
4. Also, if you plan to use it for a bedside, or end-table next to a couch or bench, you can use something like a brass, or copper tube and wire-up a built-in lamp.

Best of luck @rbhat!